# For a JSON having details from packages on a VM, convert it to CSV retaining two parent levels

Tags: jq

Given the following JSON, convert it into CSV

```
{
  "host1": {
    "packages.device-mapper-event-libs": {
      "epoch": "7",
      "version": "1.02.170",
      "release": "6.0.5.el7_9.5",
      "installdate": "1691227100",
      "arch": "x86_64"
    }
  }
}
{
  "host2": {
    "packages.device-mapper-event-libs": {
      "epoch": "7",
      "version": "1.02.170",
      "release": "6.0.5.el7_9.5",
      "installdate": "1691232631",
      "arch": "x86_64"
    }
  }
}
```

What I have tried / got

```
jq '.rows[]' | jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "\($k), \(.[$k][] | .arch), \(.[$k][] | .epoch), \(.[$k][] | .installdate | (tonumber|todate)), \(.[$k][] | .release),\(.[$k][] | .version)"'
```

This produces

```
host1, x86_64, 7, 2023-08-05T09:18:20Z, 6.0.5.el7_9.5,1.02.170
host2, x86_64, 7, 2023-08-05T10:50:31Z, 6.0.5.el7_9.5,1.02.170
```

But, this is missing the 2nd level - package name.

Expected output

```
host1, packages.device-mapper-event-libs, x86_64, 7, 2023-08-05T09:18:20Z, 6.0.5.el7_9.5,1.02.170
host2, packages.device-mapper-event-libs, x86_64, 7, 2023-08-05T10:50:31Z, 6.0.5.el7_9.5,1.02.170
```

Comment: FYI - There will be many sections for multiple packages in the actual JSON.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I just realised when I get the actual data, it is in a slightly different form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, the first jq instance (`jq '.rows[]'`) produced the stream shown as example, you can combine both into one by using a pipe within the filter.

Here's one way using `keys_unsorted` (which is like `keys` but does not sort them), but going two levels deep:

```bash
.rows[]
| keys_unsorted[] as $host | .[$host]
| keys_unsorted[] as $pkg | .[$pkg]
| [
    $host, $pkg,
    .arch, .epoch, (.installdate | tonumber | todate), .release, .version
  ]
| join(", ") # or @csv
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/EuxMm8JyPO2)

Output:

```
host1, packages.device-mapper-event-libs, x86_64, 7, 2023-08-05T09:18:20Z, 6.0.5.el7_9.5, 1.02.170
host2, packages.device-mapper-event-libs, x86_64, 7, 2023-08-05T10:50:31Z, 6.0.5.el7_9.5, 1.02.170
```

Comment: Thank you @pmf for your prompt response. It has been really helpful. I have tailored your solution to my actual need - which involved three levels - but only using 1st and 3rd.

Answer (score 1):

Using `to_entries`:

```bash
$ jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key), \(.value|keys[]), \(.value[].arch), \(.value[].epoch), \(.value[].installdate | tonumber | todate), \(.value[].release), \(.value[].version)"' file
host1, packages.device-mapper-event-libs, x86_64, 7, 2023-08-05T09:18:20Z, 6.0.5.el7_9.5, 1.02.170
host2, packages.device-mapper-event-libs, x86_64, 7, 2023-08-05T10:50:31Z, 6.0.5.el7_9.5, 1.02.170
```

Comment: Thank you @Paolo - your response has been quite useful as well.