# For a JSON having details from packages, with multiple versions, on a VM, convert it to CSV retaining two parent levels

Tags: jq

Given the following JSON which has details of packages, convert it into CSV. In case of multiple versions, pick latest - based in **installdate**

So, the JSON consists of details of each package. Some packages can have multiple versions. These *multiple* versions are held in a nested JSON element `versions`. Each version has a *installdate*. The details in the main part are not necessarily related to the *latest* version.

I am interested in getting the details of each package's *latest* version. This implies, for **kernel** package, I need to choose the element from `versions` that has the most recent, or highest, *installdate*. For packages that don't have multiple versions, the one details are picked as is - there are no versions.

```
{
  "host1": {
    "packages.kernel": {
      "epoch": "0",
      "version": "3.10.0",
      "release": "1160.102.1.0.1.el7",
      "installdate": "1698822019",
      "arch": "x86_64",
      "versions": [
        {
          "epoch": "0",
          "version": "3.10.0",
          "release": "1160.66.1.el7",
          "installdate": "1654792248",
          "arch": "x86_64"
        },
        {
          "epoch": "0",
          "version": "3.10.0",
          "release": "1160.49.1.el7",
          "installdate": "1640181036",
          "arch": "x86_64"
        },
        {
          "epoch": "0",
          "version": "3.10.0",
          "release": "1160.102.1.0.1.el7",
          "installdate": "1698822019",
          "arch": "x86_64"
        }
      ]
    },
    "packages.yum": {
      "epoch": "0",
      "version": "3.4.3",
      "release": "168.0.5.el7",
      "installdate": "1698822027",
      "arch": "noarch"
    }
  }
}
{
  "host2": {
    "packages.kernel": {
      "epoch": "0",
      "version": "3.10.0",
      "release": "1160.49.1.el7",
      "installdate": "1640181036",
      "arch": "x86_64",
      "versions": [
        {
          "epoch": "0",
          "version": "3.10.0",
          "release": "1160.102.1.0.1.el7",
          "installdate": "1698820106",
          "arch": "x86_64"
        },
        {
          "epoch": "0",
          "version": "3.10.0",
          "release": "1160.66.1.el7",
          "installdate": "1654792238",
          "arch": "x86_64"
        },
        {
          "epoch": "0",
          "version": "3.10.0",
          "release": "1160.49.1.el7",
          "installdate": "1640181036",
          "arch": "x86_64"
        }
      ]
    },
    "packages.yum": {
      "epoch": "0",
      "version": "3.4.3",
      "release": "168.0.5.el7",
      "installdate": "1698820115",
      "arch": "noarch"
    }
  }
}
```

Expected output

```
host1, packages.kernel, x86_64, 0, 1698822019, 3.10.0, 1160.102.1.0.1.el7
host1, packages.yum, noarch, 0, 1698822027, 3.4.3, 168.0.5.el7
host2, packages.kernel, x86_64, 0, 1698820106, 3.10.0, 1160.102.1.0.1.el7
host2, packages.yum, noarch, 0, 1698820115, 3.4.3, 168.0.5.el7
```

**NOTE**: A similar question was asked earlier by myself - [For a JSON having details from packages on a VM, convert it to CSV retaining two parent levels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77417285/6320605)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting the answer from the previous question:

> I need to choose the element from versions that has the most recent, or highest, installdate.

You can use `max_by` for that.

> For packages that don't have multiple versions, the one details are picked as is - there are no versions.

For that, you can use the error suppression operator `?` in combination wit the alternative operator `//`.

```bash
keys_unsorted[] as $host | .[$host]
| keys_unsorted[] as $pkg | .[$pkg]
| (.versions | max_by(.installdate))? // .
| [
    $host, $pkg,
    .arch, .epoch, (.installdate | tonumber | todate), .version, .release
  ]
| join(", ") # or @csv
```

```
host1, packages.kernel, x86_64, 0, 2023-11-01T07:00:19Z, 3.10.0, 1160.102.1.0.1.el7
host1, packages.yum, noarch, 0, 2023-11-01T07:00:27Z, 3.4.3, 168.0.5.el7
host2, packages.kernel, x86_64, 0, 2023-11-01T06:28:26Z, 3.10.0, 1160.102.1.0.1.el7
host2, packages.yum, noarch, 0, 2023-11-01T06:28:35Z, 3.4.3, 168.0.5.el7
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/HGAMFkCbBGF)

Comment: I am kind of left short of words. Just wanted to say a massive thank you for providing the new solution - building on the solution you had provided for my previous, related, question. You are just so innovative and also thorough with the way you provide a response. Your answers are a great resource for people to learn and grow and see how things 'must' be done. The answers fits perfectly into my use case and helps me with close the loop on what I wanted to do. Once again, greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you might do it.

```jq
to_entries[]
| .key as $host
| .value
| to_entries[]
| [$host, .key,
   (.value
    | if has("versions") then .versions|sort_by(.installdate)|last end 
    | .arch, .epoch, .installdate, .version, .release
   )
  ]
| @csv
```

Example output:

```csv
"host1","packages.kernel","x86_64","0","1698822019","3.10.0","1160.102.1.0.1.el7"
"host1","packages.yum","noarch","0","1698822027","3.4.3","168.0.5.el7"
"host2","packages.kernel","x86_64","0","1698820106","3.10.0","1160.102.1.0.1.el7"
"host2","packages.yum","noarch","0","1698820115","3.4.3","168.0.5.el7"
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/JErXemThVwx).

Comment: Thank you @rickhg12hs for providing a solution. What I love about this solution is introducing the branching logic with `if` statement. I can use that for future use cases.