# For a JSON having details from packages on a Windows VM, convert it to CSV retaining two parent levels

Tags: jq

Given the following JSON which has details of packages - with the host name available separately, convert it into CSV.

```
"host1"
{
  "PuTTY release 0.77 (64-bit)": {
    "version": "0.77.0.0",
    "publisher": "Simon Tatham",
    "installdate": "20220916"
  },
  "Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x86 Additional Runtime - 12.0.21005": {
    "version": "12.0.21005",
    "publisher": "Microsoft Corporation",
    "installdate": "20210816"
  }
}
"host2"
{
  "Notepad++ (64-bit x64)": {
    "version": "8.4.2",
    "publisher": "Notepad++",
    "installdate": "20230517"
  },
  "Oracle Windows VirtIO Drivers": {
    "version": "1.1.3",
    "publisher": "Oracle Corporation",
    "installdate": "20200316"
  },
  "ManageEngine UEMS - Agent": {
    "version": "11.2.2315.5.W",
    "publisher": "ZohoCorp",
    "installdate": "20230601"
  }
}
```

Expected output

```
host1, PuTTY release 0.77 (64-bit), 0.77.0.0, Simon Tatham, 20220916
host1, Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x86 Additional Runtime - 12.0.21005, 12.0.21005, Microsoft Corporation, 20210816
host2, Notepad++ (64-bit x64), 8.4.2, Notepad++, 20230517
host2, Oracle Windows VirtIO Drivers, 1.1.3, Oracle Corporation, 20200316
host2, ManageEngine UEMS - Agent, 11.2.2315.5.W, ZohoCorp,20230601
```

NOTE: A similar question was asked earlier by myself - [For a JSON having details from packages on a VM, convert it to CSV retaining two parent levels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77417285/6320605)

Comment: The JSON output is coming from a Chef knife search output

knife search node 'os:windows' -F json | jq '.rows[]'  | jq '.name, .automatic.packages'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could slurp the input file (using the `--slurp` (or `-s`) flag) to get an array of stream items, to then partition that into two-item long subarrays using `_nwise`:

```bash
_nwise(2) | . as [$name] | last | to_entries[] as {$key, $value}
| [$name, $key, $value.version, $value.publisher, $value.installdate]
| join(", ")  # or @csv
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1y_V6grjq0w)

However, given that

> The JSON output is coming from a Chef knife search output knife search node 'os:windows' -F json | jq '.rows[]' | jq '.name, .automatic.packages'

it seems more reasonable to not de-structure the items in the first place. Your jq filter suggests the following (original) structure:

```json
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "name": "host1",
      "automatic": {
        "packages": {
          "PuTTY release 0.77 (64-bit)": {…},
          "Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x86 Additional Runtime - 12.0.21005": {…}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "host2",
      "automatic": {
        "packages": {
          "Notepad++ (64-bit x64)": {…},
          "Oracle Windows VirtIO Drivers": {…},
          "ManageEngine UEMS - Agent": {…}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

From here you only need the same iteration as with the previous solutions:

```bash
.rows[] | . as {$name} | .automatic.packages
| keys_unsorted[] as $pkg | .[$pkg]
| [$name, $pkg, .version, .publisher, .installdate]
| join(", ")  # or @csv
```

```
host1, PuTTY release 0.77 (64-bit), 0.77.0.0, Simon Tatham, 20220916
host1, Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x86 Additional Runtime - 12.0.21005, 12.0.21005, Microsoft Corporation, 20210816
host2, Notepad++ (64-bit x64), 8.4.2, Notepad++, 20230517
host2, Oracle Windows VirtIO Drivers, 1.1.3, Oracle Corporation, 20200316
host2, ManageEngine UEMS - Agent, 11.2.2315.5.W, ZohoCorp, 20230601
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/A0T4UNvDsrP)

Comment: Thank you @pmf again for providing a solution to the problem and also going beyond and showing how the original data can be used to get desired output.